# Django - View is not rendering to HTML

Tags: python, django, django-forms, modelform

Pretty straight forward question….

My view named `create_view` renders data correctly out of my model and my other view named `create_view_two` view doesn’t.

How do I get my view named `create_view_two` to render data to `home.html`?

Cheers

## user_profile/views.py

```
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from django.http import HttpResponseNotFound
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404
from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from django.conf import settings
from .forms import HomeForm
from .models import Listing
from users.models import CustomUser

def create_view(request):
    form = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile = Listing.objects.all()
    user = request.user

    if request.method == "POST": 
        if form.is_valid():
            listing_instance = form.save(commit=False)  
            listing_instance.user = user 
            listing_instance.save() 
            return redirect("myaccount")

    context = {
        'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile 
    }

    return render(request, "myaccount.html", context)


def create_view_two(request):
    form_two = HomeForm(request.POST or None, request.FILES or None,)
    user_profile_two = Listing.objects.all()
    user = request.user

    context = {
        'form': form_two, 'user_profile': user_profile_two
    }

    return render(request, "home.html", context)
```

## user_profile/models

```
from django.contrib import auth
from django.db import models
from django.urls import reverse
from django.db.models.signals import post_save
from django.dispatch import receiver
from django.conf import settings
from users.models import CustomUser

class Listing (models.Model):
    image = models.ImageField(default='default.jpg', upload_to='profile_pics')
    user = models.ForeignKey(settings.AUTH_USER_MODEL, null=True, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    created =  models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, null=True)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    rank = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)    
    name = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    address = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    zip_code = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    cc_type = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    cc_number = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    cc_expiration = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    cc_cvv = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)

def create_profile(sender, **kwargs):
    if kwargs['created']:
        user_profile = Listing.objects.create(user=kwargs['instance'])

post_save.connect(create_profile, sender=CustomUser)
```

## user_profile/urls.py

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.urls import path, include
from django.conf import settings

from .views import create_view, create_view_two

urlpatterns = [
    path('myaccount/', create_view, name='myaccount'),
    path('home/', create_view_two, name='home'),
]
```

## home.html

```
 {% for profile_two in user_profile_two %}
 {{ user_profile_two }}
 {% endfor %}
```

## myaccount.html

```
{% for profile in user_profile %}
<div class="user-info-heading payments-detail">
 <p>Card Number:</p><span>{{ profile.cc_type }}</span>
<p>Card Type:</p><span>{{ profile.cc_number }}</span>
 <p>Expiration Date:</p><span>{{ profile.cc_expiration }}</span>
<p>CVV:</p><span>{{ profile.cc_cvv }}</span>    
 </div>
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: can you first check if the variable is passed to the html page by giving `{{ user_profile }}` instead of looping.

Comment: @SammyJ sure. I just tried adding `{{ user_profile.address }}` in `home.html` and nothing is passed to the page. I know I'm missing something somewhere I just don't know what. By any chance do you know what else it can be my friend?

Comment: no, remove the `.address` and see if the objects are coming, and also is there some data in the Listing() model in the database? if not there is nothing it can show, so before sending the data print the `user_profile_two` in views also

Comment: @SammyJ so I removed `.address` and no objects appeared on `home.html`. There's currently data in Listing(). I have the data from Listing() rendering perfectly on `myaccount.html` just not on `home.html`. Sorry but I'm new to Python/Django, so I know I'm missing something :/

Comment: print all data in `user_profile_two` variable in views,and then update the question with what you have done now.

Comment: @SammyJ Sounds good, I will do that later when I get home tonight.

Comment: @SammyJ so I updated `home.html`. I'll still continue to debug this tonight, please let me know what you think. thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In your `home.html` you should have:

```
{% for profile_two in user_profile %}
```

instead of:

```
{% for profile_two in user_profile_two %}
```

Given `user_profile` is the name you're giving it in the context dict.

**UPDATE**

If your code is exactly as you updated it, then your `home.html` should be like this:

```
 {% for profile_two in user_profile %}
 {{ profile_two }}
 {% endfor %}
```

Comment: so should I change context to `context = {'form': form, 'user_profile': user_profile}` as well?

Comment: The template uses the key name so it will use 'user_profile' regardless of the variable name. So no need to change the variable name. Alternatively, you could have `context = {'form': form, 'user_profile_two': user_profile_two}` and not change `home.html`

Comment: so i made that update to `{% for profile_two in user_profile %} ` in `home.html` and I can't get data to render :/

Comment: Do you get any message in the webpage or in the console? Could you add some text before the for loop in `home.html` to make sure the page _is_ rendering and only data is not?

Comment: @damores there’s no console errors and the page renders correctly. The only thing that doesn’t is the data.

Comment: @SanjeevS Yes there's data, the data won't render in `home.html` but it will in `myaccount.html` that's the issue.

Comment: @damores so I've done some debbuging and found that this view renders how I want in every template except in `home.html`. What can it be?

Comment: @SanjeevS I looked into this furyher and found that this view renders how I want in every template except in `home.html`. Any ideas what I can do to fix the issue?

Comment: I updated my answer based on your updates, let me know how it works out

Comment: @damores The only time your solution doesn't work is if I have the urls pointing to the root which is `("", create_view_two, name=''),`. If I have the urls point to a different location like  `(''test/", create_view_two, name=''),`. It works.  Why is that?